# Disk Write Queue Length

Tags: performance, winapi, disk, diagnostics

In the win32 API how can I access the average write queue length for the drive of a specific path?

I've tried looking a for a [psapi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684894(v=vs.85).aspx) function without success...

I found something about a ["physical disk object"](http://winapi.freetechsecrets.com/win32/WIN32Physical_Disk_Object.htm) but nothing about how the get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is device driver detail.  Whenever you go hunting for such details there are three places you look:

- An IOCTL, the kind you use with DeviceIoControl().  That is a dead end.
- A performance counter, Perfmon.exe is the best tool to see what is available.  Out pops category "LogicalDisk", counter "Current Disk Queue Length", instance is the drive letter
- A WMI query, best googled with a query like "wmi disk queue length".  Out pops the first hit, the [Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394262%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Lots of sample code around to show you how to use a performance counter or a WMI query in your code, google away.